# Negative and positive buttons not working on emulator

Tags: java, android

When I `setNegativeButton` and `setPositiveButton` in the alert dialog, when I run it on my mobile device which is a Hauweii phone. runs perfect, but when I run it on the emulator, the `alertDialog` shows but doesn't display the Ok or cancel but I can still click them, it's like there invisible or something, can anyone please help me?

```
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long   id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertD=new AlertDialog.Builder(Report.this);
            alertD.setTitle("Delete?");
            alertD.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete your Bmi ");
            final int positionToRemove = position;

            alertD.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
            alertD.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new  AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    bmis.remove(positionToRemove);
                    b.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }});

            alertD.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onItemClick

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Report.this);
final int positionToRemove = position;
alertDialog.setTitle("Delete?");
alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete your Bmi "));

// Setting Positive "YES" Button
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        bmis.remove(positionToRemove);
        b.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

// Setting Negative "CANCEL" Button
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

// Showing Alert Message
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: using OK as negative button is not correct.So I used YES as positive and cancel as negative and you don't want to keep position as extra variable as `final int positionToRemove = position`.You can use it directly

Comment: Yeah sorry about that i put ok and cancel in the wrong places when i was changing around the code to check it. I'll try that now thank you very much.

Comment: I just made it final. Running the emulator now to test it

Comment: ah yes you need to make that to final.bmis is your list of items and b is your adapter right?

Comment: No the buttons still do not display Yes or cancel, they are their but invisible???

Comment: you can still click on them, but no text is shown but works perfect on my Hauweii phone.